# Unity returning incorrect transform.rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the endless running game I am creating, there is a mechanic called the jump pad. It basically takes in the change in the player's position since the last frame and converts that to an angle. Then it uses that along with the `transform.rotation` of the jump pad to figure out which direction to move the player in, as if it was actually bouncing off of it.

This algorithm would've been working perfectly except for one problem: Unity was reading an incorrect `transform.rotation`. When the jump pad was rotated 45 degrees, it read 21.92615 (after being multiplied with `Mathf.Rad2Deg`.) When the jump pad was rotated 20 degrees, it read 9.949307.

At first I thought it was being multiplied by an unknown constant for some reason, but after checking it through the Calculator app I found this to be not exactly the case. After a bit more experimenting I found that the possible "unknown constants", while close enough together, did seem to have a range from around 2 to around 2.1. And while I don't have the faintest clue how this is happening, it does seem to be remarkably consistent.

So my question is: what is this problem I am facing and is there any way I can fix it? 
Brief side note: I know this is not some other problem with the code because I stripped it down to the bare minimum:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
    Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.transform.rotation.z * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK. After looking up the scripting API for `transform.rotation` and messing around a bit, I discovered that it was returning the z value of a quaternion and fixed it using the `.ToEulerAngles()` call.

Comment: Why don't you use `Transform.eulerAngles.z` directly?

Comment: quaternions can be a pain to use and the unity manual itself states that you should not use them except you know exactly what you are doing. I would recommend, as @XenoRo already hinted at, to use the eulerAngles representation of rotations when possible.